# Playing with strings

Tags: c, strings, unit-testing

I wanted to dust off my C skills, so I decided to write a couple string manipulation functions.
I aimed for simplicity and safety. Performance was not a concern.

Please be a thorough as you like. C is not my everyday language, so I might have made
some obvious mistakes. I would also appreciate extra attention to the test cases I've provided.
Are they easy to understand and expand? Is coverage good enough?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Erases a part of the string's content, filling the end with null chars.
// `startIndex` must be in a valid range inside this string. The char pointed by `startIndex` is included.
// If `count` is less than 0 or greater than the string's length, erases until the end, starting at `startIndex`.
// Does nothing if the string is empty or if `count` is zero.
size_t strErase(char * str, size_t len, size_t startIndex, int count)
{
    assert(str != NULL);
    if (*str == '\0')
    {
        assert(len == 0); // This would indicate a parameter mismatch if not true.
        return len;
    }

    // If the string is not empty, a length must be provided.
    assert(len != 0);
    assert(startIndex < len && "Index out of range!");

    // Do nothing in this case.
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return len;
    }

    // Erase ALL till the end of the string, starting from `startIndex`, if `count` is not in range.
    if (count < 0 || (size_t)count >= len)
    {
        memset(&str[startIndex], 0, len - startIndex);
        return len - startIndex; // New length.
    }

    // Erase `count` chars from an arbitrary position:
    size_t charsToMove = len - (startIndex + count) + 1; // Including the null terminator (+1)
    memmove(&str[startIndex], &str[startIndex + count], charsToMove);
    return len - count; // New length.
}

// Replaces a sequence of characters in a string by a single character.
// `startIndex` must be in a valid range inside this string. The char pointed by `startIndex` is included.
// If `count` is less than 0 or greater than the string's length, fills with `replaceWith` char starting at `startIndex`.
// Does nothing if the string is empty or if `count` is zero.
void strReplace(char * str, size_t len, size_t startIndex, int count, char replaceWith)
{
    assert(str != NULL);
    if (*str == '\0')
    {
        assert(len == 0); // This would indicate a parameter mismatch if not true.
        return;
    }

    // If the string is not empty, a length must be provided.
    assert(len != 0);
    assert(startIndex < len && "Index out of range!");

    // Do nothing in this case.
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Fill until end with the given char, starting at pos:
    if (count < 0 || (size_t)count >= len)
    {
        memset(&str[startIndex], replaceWith, len - startIndex);
        return;
    }

    int charsLeft = len - startIndex;
    memset(&str[startIndex], replaceWith, (count <= charsLeft) ? count : charsLeft);
}

// Thin wrapper over strcmp(str1, str2) == 0 for the test cases.
bool strEquals(const char * str1, const char * str2)
{
    return strcmp(str1, str2) == 0;
}

void Test_strReplace(void)
{
    // Replace end of string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 5, 6, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello++++++"));
    }

    // Replace beginning of string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 0, 6, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "++++++World"));
    }

    // Replace middle of string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 3, 5, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hel+++++rld"));
    }

    // Replace end with count overflow:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 5, 999, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello++++++"));
    }

    // Replace the whole string from the start:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 0, strlen(s), '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "+++++++++++"));
    }

    // Replace the whole string from the start with count overflow:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 0, 999, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "+++++++++++"));
    }

    // Count equal to zero is a no-op:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strReplace(s, strlen(s), 2, 0, '+');

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello World"));
    }
}

void Test_strErase(void)
{
    // Erase end of string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 5, 6);

        assert(strlen(s) == 5);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello"));
    }

    // Erase beginning of string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 0, 6);

        assert(strlen(s) == 5);
        assert(strEquals(s, "World"));
    }

    // Erase from the middle of the string:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 3, 5);

        assert(strlen(s) == 6);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Helrld"));
    }

    // Erase end with count overflow:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 5, 999);

        assert(strlen(s) == 5);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello"));
    }

    // Erase the whole string from the start:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 0, strlen(s));

        assert(*s == '\0');
    }

    // Erase the whole string from the start with count overflow:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 0, 999);

        assert(*s == '\0');
    }

    // Count equal to zero is a no-op:
    {
        char s[] = "Hello World";
        strErase(s, strlen(s), 2, 0);

        assert(strlen(s) == 11);
        assert(strEquals(s, "Hello World"));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Test_strReplace();
    Test_strErase();
    printf("Passed all tests!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Asserts are good in the test cases, but not in the actual code. First, in a release version they are no-ops, so the release doesn't check anything. Second, they result in a program termination, which is a bit drastic.
- Interfaces are unclear. What is `len`? It may only represent the length of the *character array* (vs C string), i.e. you do not rely on a terminating 0, and this, in turn, annuls the claim that `strErase` is *filling the end with null chars*. If you do rely on a terminating 0, do not have `len` as a parameter, but calculate it.
- Treating negative count is a somewhat unorthodox. Normally (if allowed at all) it means "count backwards", that is, erase a [startIndex + count, startIndex) range.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a bit of repeated code in your solution. All of the code that you've used to check specific invariants (string is not `NULL`, length is not 0 etc) can be moved into a separate function:

```
static bool check_invariants(const char *str, size_t len, size_t start_index, int count)
{
    assert(str != NULL);
    if (*str == '\0')
    {
        assert(len == 0); // This would indicate a parameter mismatch if not true.
        return false;
    }

    // If the string is not empty, a length must be provided.
    assert(len != 0);
    assert(startIndex < len && "Index out of range!");

    return count == 0;
}
```

You might want to consider returning the (potentially modified) `str` from `strReplace`, as this is more consistent with the C standard library interface.